# Windows 10 Media installers fails to start

Tags: windows-installation, windows-10

I was really excited for Windows 10, but my system was factory reset, so I had to go back to Windows 8.1. By the time I got back to Windows 8.1, I installed all 100-something updates, hoping Win10 or some prerequisite for it would install. I still have not, seen any sort f update for Windows 10. In fact the only update I see currently is a security update for Internet Explorer. I said, ok, I hear there is an ISO I can download. I thought, ok, I just download xxx.iso, run it, Windows would mount it, and I would be on my way o installation. But of course no. Microsoft wants to make things hard. I had to download some media creation tool that would either allow me to install Windows 10 right now, or make a bootable disk. This would be ok, except for the fact that it does not even start. I get a message box saying:

`Setup couldn't start properly. Please reboot your PC and try running Windows 10 setup again`

I have tried rebooting several times. Each with no more success. I have tried both 32 and 64 bit editions and both fail. How can I fix this. Everything on Google has been telling me to clean u disk space and I cleared ~40Gb using cleanmgr. I have 407Gb available right now.

Comment: You have verified you are running Windows 8.1 Update?  An in-place upgrade will fail if you are not running Windows 8.1 Update

Comment: How do I make sure it is Windows 8.1 *update*?

Comment: make sure that you have the right spects (or higher) for windows 10 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications that was my problem (i bought more hdd space)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that the installer was failing due to an earlier attempted installation of Windows 10 that failed (my computer died). In order to fix this, you enter the C:/ drive, show hidden folders, and delete the following:

- Windows.~BT
- Windows.~WS
- Windows.old

Note that you may have to enter safe mode to be able to delete some of these.

Comment: there is no need to enter safe mode to delete those files.  just run `disk cleanup` with Administrator privileges and select remove old operating systems and installation files.

Comment: Tried that, yet they persisted

Comment: hey i m unable to delete $Windows.~WS  folder and this have 2 gigs of file names BITA287.tmp.

Answer (score 5):

Stop the BITS Service to remove/rename the folders in question. No need for safemode.

Answer (score 0):

If deleting those folders didn't help you, run the installer as a different user. your profile might be corrupted.